# CircleType javascript library not working locally

Tags: javascript, circletype

I am trying to use the [CircleType](https://github.com/peterhry/CircleType) library to curve some text on a html page. I am getting some strange behaviour.

It works OK if I link directly to the circletype.mins.js file on github.

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <h2 id="demo1">This works OK</h2>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/peterhry/CircleType/master/dist/circletype.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         const circleType = new CircleType(document.getElementById('demo1'));
         circleType.radius(150);
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

If I download the js file and link to it locally I get an invalid or unexpected token error on the script. I have tried downloading the zip, cloning the git repo and running dos2unix, but can't get anything to work.

To make things even weirder, if I change the h2 value to the "Here’s some curved text flowing clockwise.", which is the value used in the online demo, it works both locally and when linking to the external file.

Does anyone have ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have `<meta charset="UTF-8">` inside `<head>` on your html file

Comment: Thank you - that was the problem.